# Is there a function other than with its first derivative and integral equal, but its $n$th derivative and $n$th integral not equal for $n\neq 1$

Tags: real-analysis

So we have a function $f(x)$ s.t. $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \int f(x)\, dx$, (up to the constant), and $$\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}f(x) \neq \underbrace{\int\int ...\int}_{n} f(x)\, dx, dx, ..., dx \quad \forall n\neq 1$$ .

If I don't give the final restriction obviously $e^{x}$ is valid, things like $\sin x$ are valid and only for periodic $n$.

Comment: what about  $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Thats not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not, and the proof is very simple:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \int f(x)\, dx \iff \\
\iff \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) = f(x)\qquad (*)$$
Now we can easily prove that (for e.g.) $\frac{d^4}{dx^4}f(x) = f(x)$:
$$\frac{d^4}{dx^4}f(x) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)\right) \stackrel{(*)}{=} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) = f(x) \iff \\
\iff \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}f(x) = \int\int f(x)\,dx\,dx\quad (n=2)$$

Comment: Also, you could solve (*) to find that $f$ must be a sum of exponentials or sinusoids.